# Setting Remote Desktop access password in KVM

Tags: desktop, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I am using KVM with libvirt for virtualization. I can access remote desktop of my vm's without any password. I want to set a Password for each vm access. I am using vinagre : for remote desktop access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In libvirt:

1. Add Hardware
2. Select Graphics
3. Select VNC Server
4. Set Password

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your domain xml directly like this:

```
# virsh edit <your-domain-name>
```

edit the element  and add attribute passwd like this:

```
<graphics type='vnc' passwd='foo'>
```

You can get more options from the article [libvirt domain xml format](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsGraphics)